# remove left and right any blank after re.split() in python

Tags: python

There is string as below

```
data_1 = '            2,000/3,000          '
```

I want the result like this.

```
data_2 = ['2,000', '3,000']
```

So I tried like this,

```
data2 = re.split('\/', data_1)
```

But the result was

```
['            2,000','3,000          ']
```

I know this result will be expected one. My knowledge comes to this line.
Because data2 is list type, so I lost a way how I can treat it. (tried with split(data2), not working)

Could you get me this? Thank you so much.

Comment: look at the `.strip()` method and iterate over your list

Comment: sorry, mistyped... not [ ], ' ' is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without having to loop over the result after doing the split.  Keeping the use of a regex expression, you can do this:

```
data2 = re.split('/', data_1.strip()) # note that you don't need to escape `/`
```

Even if your data had spaces between the components, a simple regex expression would still work, like this:

```
data2 = re.split('\\s*/\\s*', data_1.strip())
```

These both result in:

```
['2,000', '3,000']
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regex for this

```
>>> '            2,000/3,000          '.strip().split('/')
['2,000', '3,000']
```

Otherwise, loop over the list `[s.strip() for s in data_2]`

Comment: thx for reply. but I need this to separate into each text. I will add up this with other value in a row.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: If you mean you need separate variables to use them for something else, then that's outside the scope of your problem

Comment: I meant I have a original list already.

Comment: According to the question, you have a string, and are trying to use re module, which you don't need here... I'm confused

Comment: sorry for your confusing. But I am very appreciate your concern.

Answer (score 0):

```
[number.strip() for number in yourstring.split('/')]
```